# how to store hh(hour):mm(minutes) time in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently I am making scheduling system and storing information in mongodb

partial of my model looks like this

```
{
 timings: [{from: "00:00", to: "01:00"}],
 weekend: [0, 5, 6]
}
```

I am not sure if this will be good in the long run
can you please help me decide how to better store time in my documents

Comment: Why not working with the unix timestamp?

Comment: as i will not use the date only time

Comment: And? You can still use unix timestamps for hour/duration calculation.

Comment: isn't storing the date take more space in the database or that shouldn't matter ?

Comment: 1) its nots a date. Its a timestamp that represents the seconds past since Jan 01 1970. 2) To worry about the length of the timestamp sounds like a optimization for problem that does not exists. The Unix timestamp is a clear and easy way to point to a exactly moment. In my expierience i dont want to mess with hh:mm, becase in what timezone? use the UTC timestamps and you can convert them easy to any moment you want and convert them to local timezone/time.

Comment: all clear i will convert it to a timestamp and as I understood from you hopefully it will be perfect for my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB does not have any time/interval data type, so you have to build your own solution. Some general notes:

Use week days according to ISO-8601 standard, i.e. first day (1) of week is Monday. Then it will be easier to create a `Date` value with [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/). For hour values use always 24-hour format.

You may consider to store times as

```
{from: {hour: 0, minute: 0}, to: {hour: 13, minute: 0}}
```

Otherwise, when you have to create `Date` value (e.g. for comparison), then it would be:

```
{
    $dateFromParts : {
        ...,
        hour: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split: [ "$from", ":" ] }, 0 ] } }, 
        minute: { $toInt: { $arrayElemAt: [ { $split: [ "$from", ":" ] }, 1 ] } }
    }
}
```

Compared to

```
{
    $dateFromParts : {
        ...,
        hour: "$from.hour", 
        minute: "$from.minute"
    }
}
```

Another approach is to store real `Date`, e.g. `0000-01-01T13:00:00` or any other arbitrary day value. When you use such values, simply ignore the date part.

Or you store number of minutes (0..1'440) or seconds (0..86'400) from midnight. However, such numbers are not user-friendly to read.

Comment: I like how you simplified the problem for me now I understand the consequences of using custom strings, I actually think that using the first method is cleaner approach and allows making cleaner queries

Answer (score 0):

we can also store like this type:String and `hh:mm` and hh as well as mm must be length of 2 like `09 and 02` and hours must be 0 to 23 so when we have to perform the operation on it so we can done it like that sorting and ect..